# Integrating an Interpolating Function While Using MaxValue

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, code-review

I have code meant to calculate the following integral,

$I_{c}(B_{y},B_{z})=\underset{\phi'}{\text{Max}}\int\limits_{-a/2}^{a/2}\int\limits_{0}^{b}\sin(\phi'+yB_{z}+zB_{y}+\phi_{0}(y))\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$

a and b can be any real number, and the function is plotted as $B_{y}$ and $B_{z}$, with $ϕ′$ chosen to maximize the value of $I_{c}$ at a given point. $\phi_{0}$ is some function that depends on $y$. If I let $\phi_{0}$ be simple step function, then the code I have works fine, although a bit slowly.

```
a = 2;
b = 0.1;
ϕ0 = Piecewise[{{-.1, y <= .9}, {.2, y > .9}}];
ϕxy = (y*Bz);
ϕxz = (z*By);
Ib = Sin[ϕmax + ϕxy + ϕxz + ϕ0];
Ic = Integrate[Ib, {y, -a/2, a/2}, {z, 0, b}];
Ic = Limit[Ic, By -> 0];
Plot[MaxValue[Ic, ϕmax], {Bz, -20, 20}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 0.2}]
```

[image]

Now, what I would like to do is replace $\phi_{0}$ with some data that looks like,

```
0;1.0288391e-009;
5.0020013e-009;1.1142426e-009;
1.0004003e-008;1.1787119e-009;
1.5006004e-008;9.0195397e-010;
2.0008005e-008;6.5705482e-010;
2.5010006e-008;4.8513175e-010;
3.0012008e-008;4.6421934e-010;
3.5014009e-008;6.1653682e-010;
4.001601e-008;5.7840862e-010;
4.5018011e-008;3.9144468e-010;
5.0020013e-008;4.0418075e-010;
5.5022014e-008;8.5035452e-010;
6.0024015e-008;1.2769508e-009;
6.5026017e-008;1.4002402e-009;
7.0028018e-008;1.4679155e-009;
7.5030019e-008;1.7022622e-009;
8.003202e-008;1.6021381e-009;
8.5034022e-008;1.6451479e-009;
9.0036023e-008;1.8551914e-009;
9.5038024e-008;2.8063285e-009;
1.0004003e-007;4.5879194e-009;
1.0504203e-007;7.2279385e-009;
1.1004403e-007;9.9050077e-009;
1.1504603e-007;1.2553175e-008;
1.2004803e-007;1.4878258e-008;
1.2505003e-007;1.7260957e-008;
1.3005203e-007;1.8833926e-008;
1.3505403e-007;1.9728074e-008;
1.4005604e-007;2.0669339e-008;
1.4505804e-007;2.1402809e-008;
1.5006004e-007;2.1531767e-008;
1.5506204e-007;2.1615378e-008;
1.6006404e-007;2.1780509e-008;
1.6506604e-007;2.1487246e-008;
1.7006804e-007;2.1241835e-008;
1.7507004e-007;2.0817923e-008;
1.8007205e-007;2.0271397e-008;
1.8507405e-007;2.2150905e-008;
1.9007605e-007;2.4646207e-008;
1.9507805e-007;2.594411e-008;
2.0008005e-007;2.6970695e-008;
2.0508205e-007;2.7774129e-008;
2.1008405e-007;2.8204975e-008;
2.1508605e-007;2.88071e-008;
2.2008806e-007;2.9249054e-008;
2.2509006e-007;2.967092e-008;
2.3009206e-007;3.0418835e-008;
2.3509406e-007;3.1259614e-008;
2.4009606e-007;3.2198502e-008;
2.4509806e-007;3.3874011e-008;
2.5010006e-007;3.5127323e-008;
2.5510206e-007;3.6052547e-008;
2.6010407e-007;3.6552581e-008;
2.6510607e-007;3.6815228e-008;
2.7010807e-007;3.6961476e-008;
2.7511007e-007;3.7356616e-008;
2.8011207e-007;3.776615e-008;
2.8511407e-007;3.7603465e-008;
2.9011607e-007;3.7362604e-008;
2.9511807e-007;3.7159458e-008;
3.0012008e-007;3.721331e-008;
3.0512208e-007;3.7077034e-008;
3.1012408e-007;3.7118655e-008;
3.1512608e-007;3.7211397e-008;
3.2012808e-007;3.6680616e-008;
3.2513008e-007;3.6001951e-008;
3.3013208e-007;3.5299175e-008;
3.3513409e-007;3.486315e-008;
3.4013609e-007;3.4363652e-008;
3.4513809e-007;3.3438194e-008;
3.5014009e-007;3.2231583e-008;
3.5514209e-007;3.175697e-008;
3.6014409e-007;3.1646831e-008;
3.6514609e-007;3.1438949e-008;
3.7014809e-007;3.1376105e-008;
3.751501e-007;3.1077005e-008;
3.801521e-007;3.0876889e-008;
3.851541e-007;3.0741652e-008;
3.901561e-007;3.0905188e-008;
3.951581e-007;3.0700495e-008;
4.001601e-007;3.0554331e-008;
4.051621e-007;3.0235807e-008;
4.101641e-007;3.0116582e-008;
4.1516611e-007;2.9874935e-008;
4.2016811e-007;2.9978486e-008;
4.2517011e-007;2.9959012e-008;
4.3017211e-007;2.9985444e-008;
4.3517411e-007;2.9887938e-008;
4.4017611e-007;3.0069225e-008;
4.4517811e-007;3.0467266e-008;
4.5018011e-007;3.0928728e-008;
4.5518212e-007;3.1411443e-008;
4.6018412e-007;3.1668105e-008;
4.6518612e-007;3.1481819e-008;
4.7018812e-007;3.1451037e-008;
4.7519012e-007;3.1322098e-008;
4.8019212e-007;3.1188545e-008;
4.8519412e-007;3.1071011e-008;
4.9019612e-007;3.087736e-008;
4.9519813e-007;3.1019767e-008;
5.0020013e-007;3.1132166e-008;
5.0520213e-007;3.1267941e-008;
5.1020413e-007;3.1309899e-008;
5.1520613e-007;3.1581541e-008;
5.2020813e-007;3.1599919e-008;
5.2521013e-007;3.148175e-008;
5.3021213e-007;3.1433626e-008;
5.3521414e-007;3.165397e-008;
5.4021614e-007;3.1943334e-008;
5.4521814e-007;3.2222243e-008;
5.5022014e-007;3.2359658e-008;
5.5522214e-007;3.2601851e-008;
5.6022414e-007;3.268125e-008;
5.6522614e-007;3.2629561e-008;
5.7022814e-007;3.2725085e-008;
5.7523015e-007;3.29731e-008;
5.8023215e-007;3.2945945e-008;
5.8523415e-007;3.3225388e-008;
5.9023615e-007;3.344148e-008;
5.9523815e-007;3.3672549e-008;
6.0024015e-007;3.3500421e-008;
6.0524215e-007;3.3125691e-008;
6.1024416e-007;3.3252594e-008;
6.1524616e-007;3.319985e-008;
6.2024816e-007;3.3427668e-008;
6.2525016e-007;3.3970557e-008;
6.3025216e-007;3.4063314e-008;
6.3525416e-007;3.4186057e-008;
6.4025616e-007;3.4396234e-008;
6.4525816e-007;3.4952671e-008;
6.5026017e-007;3.586071e-008;
6.5526217e-007;3.7004837e-008;
6.6026417e-007;3.8068166e-008;
6.6526617e-007;3.8607473e-008;
6.7026817e-007;3.9025736e-008;
6.7527017e-007;3.9035388e-008;
6.8027217e-007;3.8905103e-008;
6.8527417e-007;3.8423549e-008;
6.9027618e-007;3.788128e-008;
6.9527818e-007;3.7392183e-008;
7.0028018e-007;3.6964275e-008;
7.0528218e-007;3.6493988e-008;
7.1028418e-007;3.6226075e-008;
7.1528618e-007;3.6095633e-008;
7.2028818e-007;3.629617e-008;
7.2529018e-007;3.6206434e-008;
7.3029219e-007;3.652299e-008;
7.3529419e-007;3.6945385e-008;
7.4029619e-007;3.7350339e-008;
7.4529819e-007;3.7913475e-008;
7.5030019e-007;3.8698912e-008;
7.5530219e-007;3.8921202e-008;
7.6030419e-007;3.9347709e-008;
7.6530619e-007;3.9302019e-008;
7.703082e-007;3.9178195e-008;
7.753102e-007;3.908215e-008;
7.803122e-007;3.8621447e-008;
7.853142e-007;3.822062e-008;
7.903162e-007;3.7719605e-008;
7.953182e-007;3.7208494e-008;
8.003202e-007;3.6399042e-008;
8.053222e-007;3.5312415e-008;
8.1032421e-007;3.4466177e-008;
8.1532621e-007;3.3975781e-008;
8.2032821e-007;3.3628231e-008;
8.2533021e-007;3.329934e-008;
8.3033221e-007;3.3146564e-008;
8.3533421e-007;3.3054627e-008;
8.4033621e-007;3.3385418e-008;
8.4533821e-007;3.3741269e-008;
8.5034022e-007;3.3928668e-008;
8.5534222e-007;3.3876428e-008;
8.6034422e-007;3.3857937e-008;
8.6534622e-007;3.4073322e-008;
8.7034822e-007;3.4486923e-008;
8.7535022e-007;3.5173836e-008;
8.8035222e-007;3.5651545e-008;
8.8535422e-007;3.5725538e-008;
8.9035623e-007;3.6100136e-008;
8.9535823e-007;3.6539733e-008;
9.0036023e-007;3.6858589e-008;
9.0536223e-007;3.7225963e-008;
9.1036423e-007;3.7228494e-008;
9.1536623e-007;3.7453343e-008;
9.2036823e-007;3.7765653e-008;
9.2537024e-007;3.7899291e-008;
9.3037224e-007;3.798122e-008;
9.3537424e-007;3.8247107e-008;
9.4037624e-007;3.8418058e-008;
9.4537824e-007;3.8706162e-008;
9.5038024e-007;3.8879813e-008;
9.5538224e-007;3.8816044e-008;
9.6038424e-007;3.8701967e-008;
9.6538625e-007;3.8586487e-008;
9.7038825e-007;3.8636843e-008;
9.7539025e-007;3.9187647e-008;
9.8039225e-007;4.0106149e-008;
9.8539425e-007;4.1198473e-008;
9.9039625e-007;4.1820867e-008;
9.9539825e-007;4.2181121e-008;
1.0004003e-006;4.2296356e-008;
1.0054023e-006;4.2441887e-008;
1.0104043e-006;4.2512017e-008;
1.0154063e-006;4.2365887e-008;
1.0204083e-006;4.2114214e-008;
1.0254103e-006;4.201183e-008;
1.0304123e-006;4.1943771e-008;
1.0354143e-006;4.1897026e-008;
1.0404163e-006;4.1799037e-008;
1.0454183e-006;4.176374e-008;
1.0504203e-006;4.1611977e-008;
1.0554223e-006;4.1587765e-008;
1.0604243e-006;4.1401783e-008;
1.0654263e-006;4.0970643e-008;
1.0704283e-006;4.0620231e-008;
1.0754303e-006;4.0316713e-008;
1.0804323e-006;4.0158797e-008;
1.0854343e-006;4.0161743e-008;
1.0904363e-006;4.0184916e-008;
1.0954383e-006;4.004746e-008;
1.1004403e-006;3.982015e-008;
1.1054423e-006;3.9554782e-008;
1.1104443e-006;3.9388833e-008;
1.1154463e-006;3.918575e-008;
1.1204483e-006;3.919682e-008;
1.1254503e-006;3.900632e-008;
1.1304523e-006;3.90155e-008;
1.1354543e-006;3.9056275e-008;
1.1404563e-006;3.8893342e-008;
1.1454583e-006;3.8753442e-008;
1.1504603e-006;3.8647115e-008;
1.1554623e-006;3.8509871e-008;
1.1604643e-006;3.8275061e-008;
1.1654663e-006;3.8011962e-008;
1.1704683e-006;3.812394e-008;
1.1754703e-006;3.8053742e-008;
1.1804723e-006;3.8173008e-008;
1.1854743e-006;3.820536e-008;
1.1904763e-006;3.8046809e-008;
1.1954783e-006;3.8047904e-008;
1.2004803e-006;3.8195705e-008;
1.2054823e-006;3.8392355e-008;
1.2104843e-006;3.8618682e-008;
1.2154863e-006;3.8972961e-008;
1.2204883e-006;3.9184031e-008;
1.2254903e-006;3.9026923e-008;
1.2304923e-006;3.8962389e-008;
1.2354943e-006;3.873235e-008;
1.2404963e-006;3.8556793e-008;
1.2454983e-006;3.8323656e-008;
1.2505003e-006;3.7988535e-008;
1.2555023e-006;3.7551003e-008;
1.2605043e-006;3.7437806e-008;
1.2655063e-006;3.7260602e-008;
1.2705083e-006;3.7232446e-008;
1.2755103e-006;3.7151935e-008;
1.2805123e-006;3.6903697e-008;
1.2855143e-006;3.6735488e-008;
1.2905163e-006;3.6457408e-008;
1.2955183e-006;3.633651e-008;
1.3005203e-006;3.6118408e-008;
1.3055223e-006;3.5951025e-008;
1.3105243e-006;3.5823801e-008;
1.3155263e-006;3.5850592e-008;
1.3205283e-006;3.5751697e-008;
1.3255303e-006;3.5826899e-008;
1.3305323e-006;3.5983851e-008;
1.3355343e-006;3.6153741e-008;
1.3405363e-006;3.6190273e-008;
1.3455383e-006;3.6137785e-008;
1.3505403e-006;3.6343317e-008;
1.3555423e-006;3.6767577e-008;
1.3605443e-006;3.7011388e-008;
1.3655463e-006;3.7015075e-008;
1.3705483e-006;3.734782e-008;
1.3755503e-006;3.76196e-008;
1.3805524e-006;3.7488103e-008;
1.3855544e-006;3.775525e-008;
1.3905564e-006;3.7747859e-008;
1.3955584e-006;3.7654193e-008;
1.4005604e-006;3.7630459e-008;
1.4055624e-006;3.7516497e-008;
1.4105644e-006;3.7689172e-008;
1.4155664e-006;3.8013211e-008;
1.4205684e-006;3.8123064e-008;
1.4255704e-006;3.8383181e-008;
1.4305724e-006;3.8203786e-008;
1.4355744e-006;3.7993303e-008;
1.4405764e-006;3.7726867e-008;
1.4455784e-006;3.7326318e-008;
1.4505804e-006;3.7432782e-008;
1.4555824e-006;3.7512397e-008;
1.4605844e-006;3.7400682e-008;
1.4655864e-006;3.7087262e-008;
1.4705884e-006;3.7142413e-008;
1.4755904e-006;3.6875011e-008;
1.4805924e-006;3.7110032e-008;
1.4855944e-006;3.7143681e-008;
1.4905964e-006;3.7021034e-008;
1.4955984e-006;3.6802899e-008;
1.5006004e-006;3.653251e-008;
1.5056024e-006;3.6441206e-008;
1.5106044e-006;3.6340756e-008;
1.5156064e-006;3.6385384e-008;
1.5206084e-006;3.6459493e-008;
1.5256104e-006;3.6782893e-008;
1.5306124e-006;3.691442e-008;
1.5356144e-006;3.6792946e-008;
1.5406164e-006;3.6925481e-008;
1.5456184e-006;3.6709639e-008;
1.5506204e-006;3.6494655e-008;
1.5556224e-006;3.6426941e-008;
1.5606244e-006;3.6481807e-008;
1.5656264e-006;3.6661133e-008;
1.5706284e-006;3.6609598e-008;
1.5756304e-006;3.6653156e-008;
1.5806324e-006;3.6607627e-008;
1.5856344e-006;3.6548925e-008;
1.5906364e-006;3.6552936e-008;
1.5956384e-006;3.6596384e-008;
1.6006404e-006;3.6884741e-008;
1.6056424e-006;3.7158304e-008;
1.6106444e-006;3.7586943e-008;
1.6156464e-006;3.8123214e-008;
1.6206484e-006;3.9287736e-008;
1.6256504e-006;4.081181e-008;
1.6306524e-006;4.1784161e-008;
1.6356544e-006;4.303506e-008;
1.6406564e-006;4.3996425e-008;
1.6456584e-006;4.4478393e-008;
1.6506604e-006;4.4628584e-008;
1.6556624e-006;4.4920972e-008;
1.6606644e-006;4.4846324e-008;
1.6656664e-006;4.4822065e-008;
1.6706684e-006;4.4784513e-008;
1.6756704e-006;4.460199e-008;
1.6806724e-006;4.4701028e-008;
1.6856744e-006;4.5019345e-008;
1.6906764e-006;4.5681471e-008;
1.6956784e-006;4.6308202e-008;
1.7006804e-006;4.6637133e-008;
1.7056824e-006;4.6912411e-008;
1.7106844e-006;4.7156417e-008;
1.7156864e-006;4.7468203e-008;
1.7206884e-006;4.7928825e-008;
1.7256904e-006;4.7919445e-008;
1.7306924e-006;4.7590156e-008;
1.7356944e-006;4.7521107e-008;
1.7406964e-006;4.7063445e-008;
1.7456984e-006;4.6149671e-008;
1.7507004e-006;4.5145482e-008;
1.7557024e-006;4.4716633e-008;
1.7607044e-006;4.4356192e-008;
1.7657064e-006;4.3536138e-008;
1.7707084e-006;4.1871856e-008;
1.7757105e-006;4.1042181e-008;
1.7807125e-006;4.115608e-008;
1.7857145e-006;4.1105077e-008;
1.7907165e-006;4.1086365e-008;
1.7957185e-006;4.0902028e-008;
1.8007205e-006;4.0631034e-008;
1.8057225e-006;4.0302268e-008;
1.8107245e-006;3.9614203e-008;
1.8157265e-006;3.9393849e-008;
1.8207285e-006;3.9456103e-008;
1.8257305e-006;3.9875521e-008;
1.8307325e-006;4.0839301e-008;
1.8357345e-006;4.1856865e-008;
1.8407365e-006;4.258164e-008;
1.8457385e-006;4.3224274e-008;
1.8507405e-006;4.3684472e-008;
1.8557425e-006;4.3440955e-008;
1.8607445e-006;4.2591096e-008;
1.8657465e-006;4.1083138e-008;
1.8707485e-006;3.9178958e-008;
1.8757505e-006;3.9155909e-008;
1.8807525e-006;3.918861e-008;
1.8857545e-006;3.8277209e-008;
1.8907565e-006;3.7304809e-008;
1.8957585e-006;3.6452258e-008;
1.9007605e-006;3.6234322e-008;
1.9057625e-006;3.6328214e-008;
1.9107645e-006;3.6354088e-008;
1.9157665e-006;3.6563245e-008;
1.9207685e-006;3.6661073e-008;
1.9257705e-006;3.6388124e-008;
1.9307725e-006;3.6472849e-008;
1.9357745e-006;3.6592049e-008;
1.9407765e-006;3.6845148e-008;
1.9457785e-006;3.798623e-008;
1.9507805e-006;3.8638708e-008;
1.9557825e-006;3.8398296e-008;
1.9607845e-006;3.8374412e-008;
1.9657865e-006;3.8172576e-008;
1.9707885e-006;3.7847789e-008;
1.9757905e-006;3.6048093e-008;
1.9807925e-006;3.4257041e-008;
1.9857945e-006;3.3681504e-008;
1.9907965e-006;3.347626e-008;
1.9957985e-006;3.3237029e-008;
2.0008005e-006;3.2905769e-008;
2.0058025e-006;3.2882003e-008;
2.0108045e-006;3.2803463e-008;
2.0158065e-006;3.3323528e-008;
2.0208085e-006;3.3419888e-008;
2.0258105e-006;3.3753616e-008;
2.0308125e-006;3.3885145e-008;
2.0358145e-006;3.3831091e-008;
2.0408165e-006;3.4214732e-008;
2.0458185e-006;3.4405396e-008;
2.0508205e-006;3.4604406e-008;
2.0558225e-006;3.3960908e-008;
2.0608245e-006;3.3488438e-008;
2.0658265e-006;3.3239026e-008;
2.0708285e-006;3.4041067e-008;
2.0758305e-006;3.4719901e-008;
2.0808325e-006;3.5098783e-008;
2.0858345e-006;3.5513756e-008;
2.0908365e-006;3.5483241e-008;
2.0958385e-006;3.5124989e-008;
2.1008405e-006;3.5021685e-008;
2.1058425e-006;3.4873256e-008;
2.1108445e-006;3.488687e-008;
2.1158465e-006;3.5450654e-008;
2.1208485e-006;3.5893998e-008;
2.1258505e-006;3.605585e-008;
2.1308525e-006;3.5940813e-008;
2.1358545e-006;3.5657038e-008;
2.1408565e-006;3.5437974e-008;
2.1458585e-006;3.5237576e-008;
2.1508605e-006;3.5176301e-008;
2.1558625e-006;3.5163281e-008;
2.1608645e-006;3.5237034e-008;
2.1658666e-006;3.5195652e-008;
2.1708686e-006;3.5365504e-008;
2.1758706e-006;3.5412827e-008;
2.1808726e-006;3.5530482e-008;
2.1858746e-006;3.5579776e-008;
2.1908766e-006;3.557067e-008;
2.1958786e-006;3.532325e-008;
2.2008806e-006;3.5178234e-008;
2.2058826e-006;3.5237491e-008;
2.2108846e-006;3.5316308e-008;
2.2158866e-006;3.554789e-008;
2.2208886e-006;3.5837769e-008;
2.2258906e-006;3.5792701e-008;
2.2308926e-006;3.5640101e-008;
2.2358946e-006;3.4839982e-008;
2.2408966e-006;3.4206129e-008;
2.2458986e-006;3.3967628e-008;
2.2509006e-006;3.3691975e-008;
2.2559026e-006;3.3651416e-008;
2.2609046e-006;3.4090046e-008;
2.2659066e-006;3.4230291e-008;
2.2709086e-006;3.4197898e-008;
2.2759106e-006;3.455709e-008;
2.2809126e-006;3.5438361e-008;
2.2859146e-006;3.5823013e-008;
2.2909166e-006;3.5934855e-008;
2.2959186e-006;3.5510074e-008;
2.3009206e-006;3.4384526e-008;
2.3059226e-006;3.3391737e-008;
2.3109246e-006;3.2721775e-008;
2.3159266e-006;3.2321948e-008;
2.3209286e-006;3.2153126e-008;
2.3259306e-006;3.1851803e-008;
2.3309326e-006;3.1665943e-008;
2.3359346e-006;3.1525925e-008;
2.3409366e-006;3.1527924e-008;
2.3459386e-006;3.1749657e-008;
2.3509406e-006;3.2018967e-008;
2.3559426e-006;3.2444644e-008;
2.3609446e-006;3.2952739e-008;
2.3659466e-006;3.3102336e-008;
2.3709486e-006;3.3420465e-008;
2.3759506e-006;3.3604171e-008;
2.3809526e-006;3.3736247e-008;
2.3859546e-006;3.3599704e-008;
2.3909566e-006;3.3165869e-008;
2.3959586e-006;3.275565e-008;
2.4009606e-006;3.2422015e-008;
2.4059626e-006;3.1847093e-008;
2.4109646e-006;3.109992e-008;
2.4159666e-006;2.972479e-008;
2.4209686e-006;2.8601187e-008;
2.4259706e-006;2.7363125e-008;
2.4309726e-006;2.5457212e-008;
2.4359746e-006;2.2413167e-008;
2.4409766e-006;2.001438e-008;
2.4459786e-006;1.7368356e-008;
2.4509806e-006;1.4050223e-008;
2.4559826e-006;1.3371515e-008;
2.4609846e-006;1.2861565e-008;
2.4659866e-006;1.248572e-008;
2.4709886e-006;1.2632882e-008;
2.4759906e-006;1.2635527e-008;
2.4809926e-006;1.3008035e-008;
2.4859946e-006;1.3657636e-008;
2.4909966e-006;1.3969935e-008;
2.4959986e-006;1.4171816e-008;
2.5010006e-006;1.4166485e-008;
2.5060026e-006;1.4141578e-008;
2.5110046e-006;1.393928e-008;
2.5160066e-006;1.4270486e-008;
2.5210086e-006;1.4889885e-008;
2.5260106e-006;1.6004168e-008;
2.5310126e-006;1.6955715e-008;
```

[image]

To do this I am trying an interpolation function, but the code is throwing a number of errors about the integral not evaluating to a number, and I am not sure why this is. What can I try to evaluate and plot the function?

```
mean = Mean[data[[;; , 1]]];
data[[;; , 1]] = data[[;; , 1]] - mean;
interp = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
By =.;
Bz =.;
b = Max[data[[;; , 2]]];
ϕ0 = interp[y];
ϕxy = (y*Bz);
ϕxz = (z*By);
Ib = Sin[ϕmax + ϕxy + ϕxz + ϕ0];
Ic = Integrate[Ib, {y, -mean, mean}, {z, 0, b}];
Ic = Limit[Ic, By -> 0];
Plot[MaxValue[Ic, ϕmax], {Bz, -20, 20}]
```